# Hooking javascript event handler from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, telerik

I have multiple treeview controls created dynamically. On dragging n dropping each node, i have to open a pop up window. Iam using the following line of code to hook a javascript event handler to the OnClientNodeDropped event of the tree node from c# code behind.

```
tree.trvEvents.OnClientNodeDropped = "ClientNodeDropped();return false;";
```

But the above line givess me the following error in mozilla.

> missing } after property list
>   ..., {"nodeDropped":ClientNodeDropped();return false;},

I am stuck with this issue for the past 2 days. Please help me with a solution.

Comment: That question has very little info in it.

Comment: How does the created (dynamic) HTML/JavaScript look like? I would guess that there are some `}` missing. e.g. `tree.trvEvents.OnClientNodeDropped = "function() { ClientNodeDropped();return false;";} `.

Comment: you have written two lines of code without {} therefore you got the error. you have to write them in as a function if you need the two lines together... such as the above comment...

Answer (score 0):

Check out Telerik's Help for [OnClientNodeDropping](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-onclientnodedropping.html)

From there, you can access the Source & Destination node, and then Cancel the dropping operation after opening the window by using

```
function ClientNodeDropping(sender, eventArgs) {
        // call your custom code here
        eventArgs.set_cancel();
    }
```

If you wish to have the node drop, and then execute the client code, you can use the [OnClientNodeDropped](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-onclientnodedropped.html) event.